# Discord.py. Как создать текстовый канал в категории?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Нужно как-то создавать канал в определенной категории на сервере и отправлять в него сообщение.

Отправку пытался сделать через

```
usr_channel = await guild.create_text_channel(str(user))
time.sleep(1)
channel = await bot.fetch_channel(str(usr_channel))
await message.channel.send('message')
```

Но попытка вышла неудачной

```
channel = await bot.fetch_channel(str(usr_channel))
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
```

Полный код:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self,payload):
    bot = self.bot
    if payload.member.bot is False:
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        user = get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
        guild = message.guild
        emoji = str(payload.emoji)
        us = [user.name]
        if emoji == "✅":
            usr_channel = await bot.create_guild_channel(user)
            time.sleep(1)
            channel = bot.get_channel(usr_channel.id)
            await message.channel.send('message')
```

```
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'create_guild_channel'
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать не ```fetch_channel``` а ```get_channel```, но перед этим импортируйте следующее: ```from discord.utils import get```, и тогда ```channel = await bot.get_channel()#id канала```

Comment: ```TypeError: object TextChannel can't be used in 'await' expression```

Comment: сделал через fetch_channel, но оно отправляет сообщение в чат через который я и создавал канал ```usr_channel = await guild.create_text_channel(str(us))
    time.sleep(1)
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(int(usr_channel.id))
    await message.channel.send('message')
 ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С документации про [`create_guild_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel)
И начните с начала с разбора своего кода, а то там такой иногда бред написан, или уже вставляйте код полностью, с `@bot.command()` и `async def func():`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command()
async def create_channel(ctx):
    channel = await bot.create_guild_channel('Name', category = 'id_категории')созадет текстовый канал в категории.
    channel1 = bot.get_channel(channel.id)
    await channel1.send('message')
```

Comment: Спасибо, я использовал немного другой метод, но вы наставили меня на путь :)